# there's lots to do OR there are lots to do?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I have been asked by my student that which one is correct considering plurality and singularity of the word, there's lots to do or there are lots to do?

Comment: Referring to work in general, we would say *There's lots to do*, 'lots' being synonymous with 'a lot'. "There are lots to do" implies a large number of items needing to be processed in some way. See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244649/there-were-lots-to-do-vs-there-was-lots-to-do-is-the-backward-existentia?rq=1)

Comment: Kate's answer is definitive here. A complication with other examples is that 'there's' is now an almost standard variant of 'there are' (qv), allowing 'There's hundreds of people in the street', at least in informal registers.

Comment: There's no discernable difference in meaning between "There's lots to do" and "There are lots to do", when talking of many items that require some kind of attention or procedure.